# How can I restart Tomcat on a Unix-Machine from a Windows-Machine with Jenkins?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

following problem: I'm running a Jenkins on one machine under Windows, on another Unix- Machine there's a Tomcat with some web-applications which I deploy with Jenkins. The problem is, that sometimes the hotdeployment of an application doesn't really work cause of Tomcats ClassLoader, it fills the Memory and sometimes changed classes are not loaded at all. So I want to be able to restart the Tomcat via Jenkins. I thought I might trigger a script on the Jenkins-Machine which can restart the tomcat service on the other machine, but how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest way is to use the SSH Plugin for Jenkins, which lets you connect to a SSH Server and enter any commands you want. Only problem left is: How can I let the Jenkins task know that the Tomcat is finished restarting? Guess thats not possible, cause the Task only triggers the "service tomcat restart"... Then it immediately is displayed as successful, which is basically is...